# Real Analysis: Show that g is integrable on [a,b] and that $\int_a^b$ $g(x)dx=$ $\int_a^b$ $f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, partitions-for-integration

Suppose f is integrable and g is bounded on [a,b], and g differs from f only at points in a set H with the following property: For each $\epsilon>0$, H can be covered by a finite number of closed subintervals of [a,b], the sum of whose lengths is less than $\epsilon$.  Show that g is integrable on [a,b] and that $\int_a^b$$g(x)dx=$$\int_a^b$$f(x)dx$.

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track, but what I'm thinking is I need to show that since g is bounded on [a,b] there is a partition P of [a,b] which has intervals smaller than $\epsilon$ and that S(P)-s(P)<$\epsilon$ for g.  I believe that should show that g is integrable on [a,b], but I don't know how to show $\int_a^b$$g(x)dx=$$\int_a^b$$f(x)dx$.

Thanks!

Comment: You have not yet accepted an answer on this site. Without any feedback from you, it's difficult to convince us to spend any effort answering your questions.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize I needed to do that.  I usually comment saying thank you.  I will go back to older questions now.

EDIT: I've accepted answers on both my previous questions.

Comment: I assume here by  "integrable" you mean à la Riemann. To simplify notations consider the function $h:=g-f$. It is bounded and vanishes outside the set $H$ as assumed, which makes it easy to find, for any $\epsilon>0$, a partition $P$ such that $-\epsilon <s(P )\le S(P )<\epsilon$. So $h$ is Riemann integrable and its integral vanishes, whence your thesis, since $g=f+h$.

Comment: Thanks, Pietro.  How do I show that $\int_a^b f(x)dx = \int_a^b g(x)dx$?

Comment: g=f+h therefore...